# Rotation in 3D space

Tags: reference-frames, rotational-kinematics

Suppose a body that rotates around an axis. But the axis also rotates. Now, the axis of the rotation of the axis also rotates, and so on. How far we can go with it? Can it be extended to infinity like a power series?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: I'm confused by the question. Certainly you can set up something like this. You're just looking for yes or no?

Comment: Clarify what is meant by "...axis of the rotation of the axis also rotates..."  Rotates about what?  About some axis that is not about the original rotation I assume?  If so, you'd just apply additional rotation matrices ad infinitum (or until you are satisfied with N being large enough).  If any of the rotation rates are not constant, then you'd need an infinite number of rotation matrices applied to get a uniform, dynamical system of equations...

Comment: Welcome to the world of robotics, where each successive arm/link pivots relative to the previous one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can it be extended to infinity like a power series?

Yes it can. This is possible not just in 3D space, but in 2D space as well. These motions are collectively called [epicycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferent_and_epicycle), and will be familiar to anyone who has produced patterns with a [spirograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirograph). Before [Johannes Kepler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Kepler) realised that planetary orbits were ellipses, astronomers used systems of epicycles to approximate the motion of the planets. According to Wikipedia:

> Any path—periodic or not, closed or open—can be represented with an infinite number of epicycles. This is because epicycles can be represented as a complex Fourier series; so, with a large number of epicycles, very complicated paths can be represented in the complex plane.